# 360 degree image of the whole sky

Tags: photography, night-sky

I look for an image that I know exists.

It is an image showing the whole sky, showing all stars and galaxies bright enough to be visible at the resolution, projected to the same shape that is commonly used for the microwave background / CMB.

I am sure the image is well known and has a name.

Can you give a reference to it?

Comment: Google is your friend. The pictures you have seen of the CMB are of the whole sky.

Comment: @RobJeffries I mention the CMP to describe the shape of the image. But I look for an image of the stars (and galaxies, of course - but these will not be recognizable even at high resolution) Google is indeed a close friend, but I did not manage to formulate the right question in this case. I made it more clear.

Comment: https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap091125.html

Comment: I wonder if you might be thinking of this projection: [What is the 2D elliptical projection of the Celestial Sphere called, and how can I make one?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22600/7982)

Comment: As Rob & uhoh said, you're probably looking for a Mollweide projection using galactic coordinates, as I described here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/293386/123208

Comment: @RobJeffries Yes, exactly this, that is the exact answer!

Comment: @a_donda Yes, that's a valid answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are night sky images in high resolution available from ESO, NASA and potantially others. They are already projected, openly licensed, and can directly be used, e.g. as skyboxes or -domes in computer graphics.

https://www.eso.org/public/images/eso0932a/

https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/3895